# Phonegap Scaling confusion and font-size scaling

Tags: html, css, cordova, scaling

I'm sorry if I come off as an amateur but I truly am one.  I'm a little confused when it comes to scaling on phonegap using the viewport.  I'm a little confused how scaling works using the viewport and maybe I'm just overthinking it.  Here is my code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

I'm trying to make the app scaled equal cross platform, and I'm not sure if I should use pixels or percentages, and how text will scale properly.  I want everything done in percentages but I feel like with margins, padding and text the percentages don't scale out properly.  So then I thought about trying to create the app with pixels, just using math to figure out the pixel ratio that I would need.

Sorry I'm new to this and i've googled over and over and just don't understand how to scale it properly without running into problems like the text being too big, or margin being off.

Comment: I guess part of my question is, with that viewport tag, can I create a page with like 1920x1080 dimensions and will it scale to fit screen for all screens?  Or is there anyway to make a set pixel height and width that will fit all screens?

Answer (score 0):

Think of the `initial-scale` and `maximum-scale` settings as zoom levels. You want `initial-scale` to be 1 and `maximum-scale` to be however much you want the user to be able to zoom in (ie. pinch to zoom). The `user-scalable` setting just says if you want the user to be able to scale the app by using pinch-to-zoom.

My typical setting is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This says that the starting scale is 1.0 (normal) and that the user can not scale (default or no value = false). As I don't allow scaling, there is no need for me to have a `maximum-scale` parameter.

Hope that helps

Comment: That does help quite a bit.  But I'm still confused on the best way to scale everything for all devices.  And the percentages seem to work well but the text and margins is my issue.  Even percentages for font sizes only seems to set the size to a basic size.

Comment: Also I'm a little confused how the max width affects everything.  Does it scale accordingly to the width if you change it to say 320px?  Sorry if I sound dumb.

Comment: Scaling everything for all device sizes is a challenge. You would be best off using a framework if you are looking at phone, tablet, and desktop. I always recommend Bootstrap for its scaling capabilities. Take a look at my SO answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141062/cordova-general-easiest-way-to-develop-for-different-screen-layouts/19142351#19142351 and take a look at the Bootstrap documentation for scaling here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.  Vote for Pedro!